# Minikube loops over the network adapter, hyperv driver, Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am a newbie when it comes to kubernetes so I want to start taking my first baby steps.

The issue is that when running the command `minikube start --driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "k8s" --alsologtostderr` after a few seconds of basic cluster setup I receive the following output:

I0809 15:44:49.860007   17056 main.go:141] libmachine: [stderr =====>] :
I0809 15:44:49.860007   17056 main.go:141] libmachine: [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive (( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).networkadapters[0]).ipaddresses[0]

which loops to infinity.

minikube version: v1.31.1
k8s switch type: both External and Internal

My apologies in advance, I was trying to find a similar stackoverflow or github entry. I have managed to find a few, but there was not a single solution solving my case.

Using docker driver when running `minikube start` works fine.

I have tried reinstalling minikube, `--hyperv-use-external-switch` and `--hyperv-external-adapter` also ends up in a loop. Also tried to restart the hypervisor services.

The cluster setup is only finished when using docker driver or hyperv driver and hyperv Default Switch.